Parse year only in excel spreadsheet
I wish to parse the “year” column which has various date formats as shown below and just leave the year only in the column,
13 march 1939, 
October 1920, 
December 10 1915 


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What format is the column? Is it text, date-time or other?

Text copied from family history site census records

You could use this simply: =--LEFT(TEXTAFTER(A1:A3," ",-1),4)

Is it all in one cell? =--RIGHT(TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(A1),","),4)

What have you tried so far? What research have you done regarding this?

In your formats, the year is always the last numeric entry. And sometimes there are commas and spaces following the year.
In 365, you can use:
=TEXTAFTER(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))," ",-1)

In earlier versions:
=MID(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), ",", ""),
        " ",
        CHAR(1),
        LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), ",", "")) -
            LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), ",", ""), " ", ""))
    ),
    FIND(
        CHAR(1),
        SUBSTITUTE(
            SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), ",", ""),
            " ",
            CHAR(1),
            LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), ",", "")) -
                LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), ",", ""), " ", ""))
        )
    ) + 1,
    99
)


For old Excel this could work as well: =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1000:$2999)/ISNUMBER(FIND(ROW($1000:$2999),A1)),1)

Or SIGN instead ISNUMBER
